# How can I get selected option value from html template to Django view.py without form tag via GET ? - Python

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, get, html-select

I have a small filter on my html template which orders the results by price. I'm trying to get the select value from the filter to later render a new queryset base on the selected value.

category.html

```
<select name="precio-filter" class="custom-select" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <option value="0" selected> Todos </option>
      <option value="1"> Gratis </option>
      <option value="2"> De 0 a $30 </option>
      <option value="3"> Mas de $30 </option>
 </select>
```

view.py

```
class CategoriaListView(ListView):
template_name = "clasecentral/categoria.html"

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoriaListView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    slug = self.kwargs.get("slug").replace("-", " ")
    context['categorias'] = categorias[slug]
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    slug = self.kwargs.get("slug").replace("-", " ")
    courses = EdxCourse.objects.filter(search_category__icontains=slug)

    #filter by price
    precio = self.request.GET.get('precio-filter')

    if precio == "0":
        queryset = courses.filter(price=0)
    elif precio == "0-30":
        queryset = courses.filter(price__range=(1,30))
    elif precio == "<30":
        queryset = courses.filter(price__gte=31)
    else:
        queryset = courses

    return queryset.order_by('title')
```

It doesn't seem to be sending any data when I select any option.
Please Help!!!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown - but you haven't shown enough. Is that select tag part of a form? Is the form submitting directly to CategoriaListView?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole thing for the select tag!

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. Where is the rest of the template?